# Add an "empty" option to a ChoiceField based on model datas

Tags: python, django, forms, choicefield

I'm defining a ChoiceField based on a model's datas.

```
field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[[r.id, r.name] for r in Model.objects.all()])
```

However I'd like to prepend my options with an empty one to select "no" objects.
But I can't find a nice way to prepend that.

All my tests like :

```
field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[[0, '----------']].extend([[r.id, r.name] for r in Model.objects.all()]))
```

Returns me a "NoneType object not iterable" error.
The only way I've found until now is the following :

```
def append_empty(choices):
    ret = [[0, '----------']]
    for c in choices:
        ret.append(c)
   return ret
```

And when I define my field :

```
forms.ChoiceField(choices=append_empty([[r.id, r.name] for r in
    Restaurant.objects.all()]), required=False)
```

However I'd like to keep my code clean and not have that kind of horrors.
Would you have an idea for me ? :p
Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An easy answer is to do:

```
field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[[0, '----------']] + [[r.id, r.name] for r in Model.objects.all()])
```

Unfortunately, your approach is flawed. Even with your 'working' approach, the field choices are defined when the form is defined, not when it is instantiated - so if you add elements to the Model table, they will not appear in the choices list.

You can avoid this by doing the allocation in the `__init__` method of your Form.

However, there is a much easier approach. Rather than messing about with field choices dynamically, you should use the field that is specifically designed to provide choices from a model - `ModelChoiceField`. Not only does this get the list of model elements dynamically at instantiation, it already includes a blank choice by default. See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

Answer (score 1):

Since this question and its answer almost solved a problem I just had I'd like to add something. For me, the id had to be empty because the model didn't recognise '0' as a valid option, but it accepted empty (null=True, blank=True). In the initializer:

```
self.fields['option_field'].choices = [
    ('', '------')] + [[r.id, r.name] for r in Model.objects.all()]
```